# Using a token deployed separately in zeppelin-solidity Crowdsale.sol contructor

Tags: crowdsale, openzeppelin

How to bring already deployed token into zeppelin-solidity Crowdsale.sol contructor? The owner is the same. What should I use instead of the "Mintable _token" below?

```
function Crowdsale(uint256 _startTime, uint256 _endTime, uint256 _rate, address _wallet, MintableToken _token) public {
  require(_startTime >= now);
  require(_endTime >= _startTime);
  require(_rate > 0);
  require(_wallet != address(0));
  require(_token != address(0));

  startTime = _startTime;
  endTime = _endTime;
  rate = _rate;
  wallet = _wallet;
  token = _token;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the token you created is of type `MintableToken`, then all you have to do is supply the address of the token contract to the contstructor as the `_token` parameter. You'll also have to set the owner of the token to be the crowdsale contract, since it needs to have permissions to mint tokens.

If the token contract you created isn't of type `MintableToken`, then it wont work because it wont have the necessary functions.

Comment: If it's not mintabke, can I just transfer token to the contract address manually?